# zooming into mandelbrot set does not work as planned

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, mandelbrot

I changed some things but i still have a similar problem. I am working on Mandelbrot zoom. I try to zoom in deeper at branches. I count the consecutive points in the set and return the branch if it reaches the defined length. Then I zoom into that area and repeat. But the change gets smaller and the returned branch is nearly the same as the last one.

variables

```
X0,Y0,X1 = verticies of current area
branch = current branch
n = number of iterations
p = how many times i want to zoom
b = minimum length of branch i am looking for
c = current complex number
z = current value
k = pixel size
```

the function that returns the branch

```
def fractal(n, X0, Y0, X1):      # searching for new branch
    branch = []          
    k = (X1 - X0) / x_axis      # pixel size
    b = 5               # the number of black points int the set i am looking for
    
    for y in range(y_axis):         
        try:
            for x in range(x_axis):                                                 
                c = X0 + k * x + Y0 - k * y * 1.j    # new c     
                z = c

                for m in range(n):                
                    if abs(z) <= 2:
                        z = z * z + c                  # new z
                    else:
                        break
                if abs(z) <= 2:                                          
                    branch.append((x,y))                # the coordinates for those points   
                else:                                      
                    if b < len(branch)  < 50: 
                        raise BreakOutOfALoop       # break if a branch was found
                    branch = []
        except BreakOutOfALoop:
            break
    return branch, k
```

the function that calculates the verticies of the new area

```
def new_area(branch, X0, Y0, X1, k):    # calculating new area        
    print(branch)
    X0 = X0 + k * branch[0][0]
    Y0 = Y0 - k * branch[0][1]
    X1 = X1 + k * branch[-1][0]              # new area verticies  
    return X0, Y0, X1
```

the loop that calls the functions

```
for i in range(p): 
    
    areaImage = Image.new('RGB', (x_axis,y_axis), "white")
    area_pixels = areaImage.load()                              # image load

    branch, k = fractal(n,X0, Y0, X1) 
    X0, Y0, X1 = new_area(branch, X0, Y0, X1, k)    
         
    file_name = "/" + str(i) + "_" + str(n) + "_" + str(x_axis) + "_" + str(y_axis) + ".png"                    # image save
    areaImage = areaImage.save(f"{areaImage_path}{file_name}")
```

What am I overlooking?

Here are some pictures for different p.
[p = 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBcZc.png)
[p = 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP8Wc.png)

Comment: Without knowing what each parameter does, its hard for me to know exactly what is happening, but the error is being caused by trying to access an empty list (branch). The p parameter isn't the only issue though, its a combination of your parameters. at 200x200 resolution, the error occurs on lower values of p. Anyway, when p is 11 with your other parameters set, I think the problem is that the `if abs(z) < 2` condition is never met before you break out of the loop.

Comment: I thought so too but what is the difference btween `p = 8` and `p = 9`  in this case?

Comment: not really sure, as I don't understand how your code works. What I have figured out is changing the image size and the value of n will affect the critical point at which the p loop errors. Larger images make it error at lower values. I think at those values, the magnitude of your complex numbers start higher than 2 or something. I suggest using an IDE with a debugger to try to see what is going on.